# SSAS limited to one partition

Tags: azure, ssas, partition

I have SSAS model (tabular) on Azure and I'm trying to add a partition to a table.
When I try to deploy my solution, I get the following error message :

Failed to save changes to the server. Error returned: "This edition of SQL Server Analysis Services supports only one partition per table."

How do I configure the number of partition allowed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution : the problem was the pricing of my Azure Analysis Service.
I switched it from Basic tier B2 to Standard tier S1. I am now able to use multiple partitions.